# Неправильно определяется высота элемента div.height()

Tags: jquery

Есть две колонки контента

```html
<div id="main-bar"> 
...
</div>
<div id="side-bar"> 
...
</div>
```

Мне нужно чтобы при разнице высот двух колонок, высота одного из элементов второй колонки изменялась, и занимала пустое место.

Пытаюсь так:

```js
 var mainBar = $('#main-bar').height();
 var sideBar = $('#side-bar').height();
 var hHelper = (mainBar - sideBar);
 if (mainBar > sideBar) {
  $('.sticky-helper').height(hHelper);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Почему-то `var mainBar = $('#main-bar').height();` определяет высоту не правильно. В консоль выводится одно число, в разметке показывается другое. Внутри элемента много вложенных элементов с другими объектами.

Comment: .outerHeight(true) пробовали?

Comment: @Konst Да, пробовал. грешу на то, что там есть блок внешней рекламы, который почему-то не учитывается в высоте. Не знаю уже что делать

Comment: Можно еще поместить оба блока в общий блок с `display: flex;` — высота одного будет подстраиваться под друого → https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/hc74kotj/

Answer (score 3):

Запускайте код не по `ready` а по `load`, тогда будет нормально. После ready еще не успела загрузиться реклама\картинки, и их высота не высчитывается. `$(window).on("load", function () { /* тут Ваш код */ })`